# What motivated Whitehead to choose "Cogredience"?

Tags: metaphysics, terminology, whitehead

I'm not a native english speaker, so I was not familiar with the term "cogredience" when I first saw it in *Concept of Nature*. frankly, it seems like its a word Whitehead used in a different context than was originally intended.

In a quick Google search, I [found](https://www.wordnik.com/words/cogredient) that the term is originally "cogredient", and has two definitions:

- (mathematics) system of variables subject to undergo linear transformations identical with those of another system of variables.
- (literally) coming together.

Next I saw that in *Process and Reality* Whitehead defines "cogredience" (emphasis mine):

> The percipient event is always here and now in the associated present duration. It has, what may be called, an absolute position in that duration. **Thus one definite duration is associated with a definite percipient event**, and we are thus aware of a peculiar relation which finite events can bear to durations. I call this relation  'cogredience.'

So, in a way, it seems that the usage of "cogredience" for Whitehead is a **correlation** between duration and percipient event.

I wonder, is there any specific reason for Whitehead to use the convoluted, non-conventional term "cogredience" rather than simpler terms such as "correlation" or "correspondence"? (that is, aside from the word being obviously part of his mathematical lingo)

Comment: I doubt that even many native English mathematicians are familiar with the word unless they work on invariants of bilinear forms and have a liking for old school approach. One reason Whitehead would use it is to mark his distinctive concept vs something generic like "correlation" or "correspondence". It also suggests a stronger relation than those two, cogredient variables are linked by a linear transformation and so change "in concert" in a more definitive sense.

Answer (score 0):

Think of the word 'ingredient' and what 'co' means. What Whitehead is trying to convey in a complex way (as a person who has to hold his recognition in an academic environment), is a kaleidoscope of existence, where each entity is an ingredient emerging and morphing along with 'other' ingredients in a 'co' relationship, like an 'existence kaleidoscope'. I wrote about this in my Medium essay titled ['Explorations in Synechism: Nature Rarer Uses Yellow'](https://medium.com/@SarahCTyrrell/explorations-in-synechism-nature-rarer-uses-yellow-7702608ee5b7). Hope that helps! :)